# JavaScript Freezes Browser

Tags: javascript, browser, countdown, freeze

I'm trying to make a countdown timer for each row of a table based on a hidden field containing the ammount of seconds to finish. Here is what I have done so far:

```
function countdownProcedure() {
    var interval = 1000;
    var i = 0;
    var seconds;
    $(".rfqTbl tr").each(function() {
        if(i > 0) {
            seconds = $(this).find("#sqbTimestamp").text();
            var days = Math.floor(seconds / (60*60*24));
            seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
            var hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60*60));
            seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
            var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
            seconds -= minutes * 60;
            if(days < 1) { days=""; }
            $(this).find("#countDown").html(days + "<pre> Days</pre> " + hours + "<pre>:</pre>" + minutes + "<pre>:</pre>" + seconds);
            if(days > 1) {
                $(this).find("#countDown").css({
                    'color':'#2A7F15',
                    'font-weight':'bold'
                });
            };
            if(days < 1) {
                $(this).find('#countDown').css('color','red');
                $(this).find('#countDown pre:nth-of-type(1)').css('display','none');
            }
            if(seconds < 10) {
                $(this).find("#countDown").append("&nbsp;");
            };
            if(minutes < 60){ interval = 1000; };
        }
        i++; 
    }); 
    setInterval(countdownProcedure,interval);
};
```

However, my problem is that I'm trying to get this function to run (realistically every second or 30) so that the time shown would update and hence 'countdown'. The problem I am having is in firefox and safari the browsers are just hanging after the first countdown and chrome is doing nothing (I guess it has a safe guard to prevent it from hanging).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: why are you continually searching for an ID from the context of the elements?? Am I to understand you have duplicate ID values? *Please say no, but I have the eerie feeling you will say yes*

Answer (score 3):

You are running a multitude of `setInterval()` calls, so the event queue gets crowded with your function.

I think, what you mean is more like [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) at the end of your function.

```
function countdownProcedure(){
  // all your logic
  setTimeout(countdownProcedure,interval);
};
```

The difference is, that `setInterval()` will run your code **every x seconds**, until you tell it to stop.

`setTimeout()` on the other hand, just runs your code **once after x seconds**.

Answer (score 0):

Change all ids for clases Ex: **#sqbTimestamp** for **.sqbTimestamp**

in an HTML document, should exists only 1 element with some id, if you set multiple elements with same id, unexpected results (as browser hanging) can occurrs.

Also, you are setting **days=""** and then do the following compare **if (days > 1)**

Comment: Although this is a valid comment, I doubt the browser hangs on duplicate ids. The problem is just, that you can't be sure, which element you access, when using the ID.

Comment: Agreed, the browser *hang* is definitely stacking timeouts. I have seen this before. However, all of these points are valid. Maybe consider moving this to a comment.

Comment: You are right, maybe my english is not so good. I reffer that with the setInterval executing each time for each row resetting the time this will come to a hang.

Comment: You never mention the timeouts, only the ID values. You are correct that unexpected results can happen, however in this case those results will not be browser hangups.

Comment: Sometimes i think faster that I write. Ok He has an each function, in this each function he is calling multiple times the same process for the same ids, and then he do mathematical operations, this is done multiple times for the setInterval, then calling multiple times the same ids (thinking that is calling different objects) and processing multiple times the operations is lowering the browser performance until the momento that the browser hangup.

Answer (score -1):

I think your algorithm is wrong. You are recursively setting intervals which are calling themselves every time and setting new intervals and so on...
You must change your algorithm a bit to get it clean.